# Chrome fails to export private key when packing an extension

Tags: key, private

So as I'm trying pack an extension I made every time I try to pack it it just says Failed to export key. I have a Chromebook so I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I believe it's just something Chromebook doesn't have.

Answer (score 11):

I realize it has been a while since your post, but I ran into this today. It was due to permissions in the folder where the extension was. Chrome tries to create the key file and crx file one folder up from the folder you provide as the extension root which can be a problem if you don't have write permission to that folder.

I moved my extension to a sub-folder of the one I had originally created for it, tried again and it worked.